# Cake PHP Model Associations - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: cakephp, model-associations

No matter how many times I read through the documentation, look at examples I cannot get my model to "associate" with another.

Here is my example:

I have a table called *kits* and a table called *grades* (read books and authors).

*kits* looks like this (simplified):

1. id (PK)
2. grade_id (FK)
3. name

*grades* looks likes this:

1. id (PK)
2. code

Each kit will have only 1 grade. I don't see any issue with naming conventions, it follows as prescribed in the API.

--

I have a controller called KitsController.php that looks like this:

```
class KitsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        //simple find that limits to one (for readability)
        $pigs = $this->Kit->find("all", array( 
            "limit" => 1
        ));

        $this->set("pigs", $pigs);
    }
}
```

I have a corresponding index.ctp file that outputs the variable $pigs (not a production level variable name I know).

--

I have my model called KitModel.php

```
class Kit extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = "Grade";//here is where I am confused
}
```

...and an empty Grade model for a placeholder

```
class Grade extends AppModel {

}
```

--

**The Problem:**

When the array prints out on the page it looks like this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
    [Kit] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [grade_id] => 1 
        [name] => Ferrari 
)   )   )
```

From my understanding when I print out the results it should include the Grade information along with the kit information. It certainly does for every example I have seen online. I have also tried different relationships (hasOne, etc) but to no avail. Also I have tried the long form by passing in an array with the classname and foreign key but if my schema matches cakePHP convention I shouldn't have to do that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

> I have my model called KitModel.php

Your model filename is incorrect. It should be `Kit.php`. If CakePHP doesn't find a model file named as per convention it uses an AppModel instance for the model.

Comment: Probably clear from this answer, but your 'Grade' model should thus be in a file named `app/Model/Grade.php`

Comment: Jeez, I don't know how I missed that! I knew it would be something obvious. I should have taken a break and come back to it fresh. I will try it out, thanks!

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.